# Make one column dependent on association Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a table called **HOUSE**. And it has a column named **STATUS**.

I also have a table called **TASK** and it also has a column named **STATUS**.

Each house has many tasks. And if there's one task that has a status of `inProgress`, the house status shall be `inProgress`. And if all of the tasks are `done`, then house is `done`.

I want this status column of the house be dependent on the status of its all tasks.

When I call `/getHouses`, here's what I do to add a property called **status** to each house object, because currently I have no **STATUS** column in the **HOUSE** table.

```
exports.getMyHouses = (req, res) => {
  const page = myUtil.parser.tryParseInt(req.query.page, 0)
  const limit = myUtil.parser.tryParseInt(req.query.limit, 10)

  db.House.findAndCountAll({
    where: { userId: req.user.id },
    include: [
      {
        model: db.Task,
        as: "task",
        include: [
          {
            model: db.Photo,
            as: "photos"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        model: db.Address,
        as: "address"
      }
    ],
    offset: limit * page,
    limit: limit,
    order: [["id", "ASC"]],
  })
    .then(data => {
      let newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
      const houses = newData.rows

      for (let house of houses) {
        house.status = "done"

        const tasks = house.task
        for (let task of tasks) {
          if (task.status == "inProgress") {
            house.status = "inProgress"
            break
          }
        }
      }

      res.json(myUtil.response.paging(newData, page, limit))
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error get houses: " + err.message)
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "An error has occured while retrieving data."
      })
    })
}
```

---

EDIT: I just realized that perhaps I can update the house's status column each time there's an update in the task's status. I've never thought about this before.

But I would still love it if anyone could confirm that this is a good strategy or if there's a better one.

Comment: The option you have is viable as long as filtering by the house's status isn't something you require. This would essentially be called a virtual field (since it isn't something directly from the database). If you do need to filter by this field, you'd then need to query for all the tasks InProgress and get the unique house IDs.

Comment: Thanks, Steven! Why not post this as an answer? What do you say about my idea (see edit)?

Comment: Hey Glenn, I posted my answer but I generally tend to avoid posting answers that are opinion vs fact so take my answer with a grain of salt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option you have is viable as long as filtering by the house's status isn't something you require. This would essentially be called a virtual field (since it isn't something directly from the database). If you do need to filter by this field, you'd then need to query for all the tasks InProgress and get the unique house IDs.

You could update the house's status column on task update too but you could run into some race conditions if, for example, multiple requests were being made to update tasks to the same house. Make sure to run a transaction here if you were too. Querying/filtering for houses with InProgress tasks would be much faster since you can query it directly. However, updates would be slower since you'd need to run a task update, a count query on tasks, and an update query on the house.

Both have it's pro's and con's, it mainly depends on your application design's requirement.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this. Your explanation kinda relates to my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860863/sequelize-get-all-data-with-custom-where perhaps if you have time take a look at it. But like in this current question, in that new question I found somehow a solution --> don't use pagination.